# Efficiency of Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, performance

Q1. I would like to confirm whether Version 1 of below code is more efficient than Version 2? I'd like to know for future reference so I will be writing codes according to the style of either V1 or V2.

Q2. How does one measure efficiency of the code? (Doesn't have to be in depth, I just want to have a rough idea)

Version 1:

```
function average(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a,b) {    return a + b;  }) / array.length;
}
```

Version 2:

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a,b) {    return a + b;  }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}
```

Edit: assuming that at a later stage I would be writing much more complex code and I would like to get into the habit of writing efficient code now. I know that for simple one-liners there's no explicit difference.

Comment: why do't you try a benchmark like http://jsperf.com/

Comment: There's no discernible difference between those two versions; write in the way that makes it easy to maintain, first and foremost.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/anonymous-vs-named-function-passing

Comment: One approach is slower on some browsers, and the other approach is slower on other browsers. On some browsers, they are almost exactly the same. In any case, the difference isn't big enough to really matter.

Comment: You are creating a closure by creating the function sum inside your average function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have the same result. Or difference will be negligible. Depends on JS engine and how good its optimizer is.

As others suggested you can use jsperf.com for speed tests.

But if you really care about performance then check third case here
http://jsperf.com/anonymous-vs-named-function-passing/3

Answer (score 1):

These functions are equally efficient from a big-O perspective.  The reason they are the same, is that they both pass a function into `reduce()` (the way in which the function is declared is different, but it's the same underlying structure and thus the same efficiency). The functions are otherwise the same. If I were you, I'd opt for the second case as it is probably easier to maintain.

If you want, you can use a speed test, but honestly it's a waste of your time as these two approaches are identical.

Answer (score 1):

With a sequential loop, it's far faster:
http://jsperf.com/anonymous-vs-named-function-passing/2

```
function average3(array) {
      var sum =0;
      for( var i=0, len=array.length; i< len; i++ )
        sum+=array[i];
      return sum/array.length;
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! I like writing these kind of loops and far easier than remembering individual functions.

Comment: @apollo methods such as `.reduce()`, `.map()`, etc. are part of the standard arsenal of someone who at least dabbles in functional programming; to say that it's hard to remember those is somewhat unrealistic.

Comment: Okay good I'm hoping some day those will become second nature to me similar to what sequential loops are.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same... but you could optimize by avoiding to create a new closure of the sum function.

```
function sum(a,b){
    return a+b;
}

function average(array){
    return array.reduce(sum) / array.length;
}
```

This way sum won't hold a reference to `array` in its context; and a new instance of sum with the context won't be necessary. Remember that a closure will hold a reference of the arguments of the function that contains it *even if you don't use those arguments*.

This means that a new function `sum` won't be instantiated every time that you call `average`.